# How do I access a shared google drive document from my yahoo?

Tags: google-drive, google-account

Someone keeps sharing documents with my Yahoo account, because it is my main email. But when i click the documents, it opens them in google drive, and my google account does not have access to them. Can i somehow open them in google drive with my yahoo account instead of my google account? I can't just sign in on google with my yahoo account, because well its not a google account. Everything online i can find is only for yahoo apps on mobile devices, or tells me to find a button or setting that does not appear for me within yahoo. pls help

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. You might add your Yahoo email address as a secondary/alternate email address to your Google account. This is explained in the Google Drive Help Center. See [Share files with non-Google Accounts](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6033939). I suggest you use Google Drive for help. It could be reached very easily from the app. Also, look carefully at the error messages and the app user interface. They include tips, hints, and links that might help you to save time and to learn the app jargon/argot. Regarding posting questions on this site please check out [ask].